# Seeking help copying the value from one cell to another using VBA.

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help with excel Macros. To be exact if there is a value in Column A then copy that value in next 2 cells under that value (Say a value exist in A1 then it should copy in A2 and A3). This same thing should go till Column K. (Please Note : If there is already a value in A3 then it should copy the value of A1 to A2 and should not overwrite A3).

Comment: How does your table look like? Is it only values in A1:K1 that need to be copied, or every 4th row? Any value or a value that you specify somewhere?

Comment: This same thing should work for the entire workbook (i.e. say another value is in A13, A18, A20,A25 and so on).

Comment: So go through each cell in A:K, and copy it into the two cells below it, as long as these two cells are empty? Let's say, you copy the value from A1 into A2 and A3. A4 is empty. Should the value of A2 then be copied into A4? Also, this would go forever, until excel runs out of rows. Should it end 2 rows below the original last-row?

Comment: Look, to make things simple let me quote it like this. Say a value is in A2 then that value should get copied in next 2 cells (i.e. in Cell A3 & A4). In case there is already a value in A4 then it should not overwrite the value in A4. It should shop in A3 only. Similarly again another value can be in A10 which should be copied in next two cells, again next value can be in A15 and so on. Now absolutely same thing should go on from column A to Column K. Am i clear now ????

Comment: Not really. Let's take your example: a value is in A2. A3 and A4 are empty. After copying that value to A3 and A4, there is now values in A3 and A4. Now should the code copy the value of A3 to the two cells below it, or in this case, since A4 also has a value already, to A5? Please post how your table looks like (edit it into your question).

Comment: Extremely sorry to see that you still not understood even after breaking my question in fragments. "After copying that value to A3 and A4, there is now values in A3 and A4". Certainly it should not. Whatever raw data is provided in the excel sheet on that the code is suppose to run once.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about your table and data, but below code might give you and idea for your implementation. Below code deal till column C. A1 to C2 and later on increment by 5

```
Sub copy()
Dim lngVar As Long, i As Long, j As Long
j = 2
lngVar = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lngVar
    Range("C" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
    j = j + 5
Next i
End Sub
```

I have not tested above code as I do not have excel installed :(

Comment: You can refer to the explanation i have added recently. Hope it will give you a better idea of what i am trying to say and what i am expecting.

Comment: so far what have you tried? if you have any code with you which give some result please share your code so we will help you.